# Texshop / bibtex errors in docs that used to work

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, texshop

I'm running Mac OS 10.13.1 (High Sierra) and Texshop Version 3.89. I opened Texshop for the first time in about 4 months today, and started to work on a document. I use Zotero to generate my BibTex file, also as usual. But I keep getting the following error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: My_Paper.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file My_Paper.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file My_Paper.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file My_Paper.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

I thought I was doing something wrong because I was rusty, so I went back to a paper I wrote 2 years ago that definitely worked. There, I saved the `.tex`, `.cls`, `.bib`, and `.pdf` files, but when I ran the .tex file, I got the same error.

Is this a problem with TexShop under High Sierra, or is there something else I have to update to get these old papers to run?

As a minimum working example, this `.tex` file works in Overleaf, but gives me the error above in Texshop:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{paperbib}


\begin{document}
\title{Academic Paper:\protect\\With a Subtitle}
\author{Joan Q. Public}
\maketitle

Blah blah blah. 

Blah blah Einstein's Theory\autocite{einstein} which predicted blah.

The New York Times\footcite{nyt} reported blah blah. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` you need to tell TeXShop to process the bibliography with `biber` not `bibtex` (which is the default). Try adding `% !BIB TS-program = biber` to the top of your file and recompiling the bibliography or use the `pdflatexmk` engine. Also you're running quite an old version of MacTeX (2015); you might want to update to MacTeX 2017.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Taking things in order, I updated to MacTeX 2017.  I still get the same error message, but now it starts with `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)`

Comment: Adding `% !BIB TS-program = biber` to the top of my `.tex` file worked!  **Thank you!**  Do I have to do that to every file from now on, or is there a way I can adjust TeXshop to handle it for me?

Comment: I've always used just `bibtex`, and that's what the TeXshop Preferences are set for.   What's weird is that `.tex` and `.bib` files that worked before suddenly don't work. What changed?

Comment: Sorry to moewe, Johannes_B, Andrew, Kurt and egreg that they felt this was a duplicate question, but when I asked it, I really thought it was a TeXshop problem, not a `bibtex`/ `biber` issue, since `.tex` files that used to run perfectly suddenly stopped running when I updated TeXshop.